# OpenGL ES 3.1 "imageStore" does not work on Mali T760

Tags: android, mobile, graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.1

I am working to make the Mobile Graphics program using OpenGL ES 3.1.

I verified that my program is working well on the Adreno OpenGL ES 3.1 Emulator (My Graphic card is Nvidia GTX 580). But, when I install my program on a smartphone (Samsung Galaxy Note 4 - Mali T760), a serious problem occurs.

I use "imageStore" in shader function.
This function is working well on Emulator, but only write 0 on android phone.

Is there any issue or solution on this problem?

Comment: You need to post an example. Like C, GL ES has a lot of edge cases with undefined behaviour, so it may simply be that the emulator is more forgiving in this case than the Mali driver. If that's the case, fixing your code will make it work on your target phone.